# How to show the input tags in this code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(function() {
$("input").hide();
$("li").on("click",function (){
    $(this).hide(500);
    var inp = $(this).find("input");
    $(inp).show(500)
    })
});
```

i want it to show only the input field and not the text in span tags

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Bookmarks</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Bookmarks</h1>
    <h2>click on the items below to edit</h2>
    <ul id="list">
    <li> <span>apple</span> <input value="apple"> </li>
    <li> <span>banana</span> <input value="banana"> 
</li>
    <li> <span>orange</span> <input value="orange"> </li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my 1st post on this site so sorry for any mistakes i make.
Iam trying to make a bookmarking system

Comment: Please provide also the html part

Comment: what is happening with what you have now? did you try to debug it before posting in SO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` in your click handle refers to that `<li>` node, so when you call `.hide()` on it all sub nodes are also hidden. You should target `span` elements inside your `li`.

```js
$(function() {
  $("input").hide();
  $("li").on("click", function() {
    $('span', this).hide(500);
    $('input', this).show(500);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Bookmarks</h1>
<h2>click on the items below to edit</h2>
<ul id="list">
  <li> <span>apple</span>
    <input value="apple"> </li>
  <li> <span>banana</span>
    <input value="banana">
  </li>
  <li> <span>orange</span>
    <input value="orange"> </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @TheTechWeaver If the answer has solved your issue please accept it. Additionally I've updated your snippet a little bit: https://jsfiddle.net/ej200xxp/2/

Answer (score 0):

You want this ? [See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uxgkxgt6/1/)

```
$("input").hide();
$("li").on("click",function (){
    $(this).find('span').hide(500);
    var inp = $(this).find("input");
    $(inp).show(500);
});
```

Comment: Yes and i want to change the value of span text to what i enter inside of input also thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

if you can only one text field to show try this code

```
<input type="text" name="" value="hello">
<ul>
 <li>test</li>
</ul>
```

your .js file extend here

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../library/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$("input").hide();
$("li").on("click",function (){
    $(this).hide(500);
    $('input').show(500)
    })
});   
</script>
```

if you can click on li li will be hide and using `input` keyword text field will be shown